# PHP Redirect based on Mysqli query

Tags: php, mysqli

I am new to coding and self-study. So please be patient with me, I am trying to create a login script that redirects users to different pages based on their `groupid` in `mysql` table.
**Here is a sample of my code:**

```
public function login(){        
        $errorMessage = '';
        if(!empty($_POST["login"]) && $_POST["loginId"]!=''&& $_POST["loginPass"]!='') {    
            $loginId = $_POST['loginId'];
            $password = $_POST['loginPass'];
            if(isset($_COOKIE["loginPass"]) && $_COOKIE["loginPass"] == $password) {
                $password = $_COOKIE["loginPass"];
            } else {
                $password = md5($password);
            }   
            $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM ".$this->userTable." 
                WHERE email='".$loginId."' AND password='".$password."' AND status = 'active'";
            $resultSet = mysqli_query($this->dbConnect, $sqlQuery);
            $isValidLogin = mysqli_num_rows($resultSet);    
            if($isValidLogin){
                if(!empty($_POST["remember"]) && $_POST["remember"] != '') {
                    setcookie ("loginId", $loginId, time()+ (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));  
                    setcookie ("loginPass", $password,  time()+ (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
                } else {
                    $_COOKIE['loginId' ]='';
                    $_COOKIE['loginPass'] = '';
                }
                $userDetails = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultSet);
                $_SESSION["userid"] = $userDetails['id'];
                $_SESSION["name"] = $userDetails['first_name']." ".$userDetails['last_name'];
                header("location: ***WANT TO QUERY MYSQL TABLE AND BASED ON GROUPID REDIRECT TO RESPECTIVE GROUP LANDING PAGE STORED IN MYSQL TABLE***");       
            } else {        
                $errorMessage = "Invalid login!";        
            }
```

I have two sql tables, The first one using to `login users` + `store info` about the user.
The Second one contains the `urls` of where I would like to redirect and `id` is `foreign key` that matches to `groupid` in the first table.
 Is there any way to use `groupid` to place in

```
header("location: sampleofwhatiwouldliketochangebasedongroupid.php")
```

Thank you for your consideration and your help.

Comment: You should start by learning good habits. Use prepared statements and bound parameters instead of concatenating variables into the query.

Comment: You also shouldn't store plaintext passwords, use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`.

Comment: Always `exit()` after `header('Location: ...');`

Comment: @Dharman Thank you for your input! I am reading up on all that you sent me and will repost fixed code once I understand all that I have read.

Answer (score 1):

Join the user table with the redirect table.

```
$sqlQuery = "SELECT u.id, u.first_name, u.last_name, r.url FROM ".$this->userTable." AS u
             JOIN ".$this->redirectTable." AS r ON u.groupid = r.id
            WHERE email='".$loginId."' AND password='".$password."' AND status = 'active'";
...
header("Location: " . $userDetails['url']);
```

Replace `url` with the actual name of the column with the redirect URL.

Comment: I am going to do my research on the information sent me and will redo my code based on what I learn. Thank you kindly for this!